# Ksh script no parent error

Tags: ksh, test

I want the script to open a file and read the file line by line then count the number of commas per row/line. If that is more than the $2 parameter value,  then write the offending line number (from my read loop) and the total commas found to a log file.

I'm not sure what's wrong, but I'm getting a no parent error.

```
#!/bin/ksh
filename=$1 #First input parameter path with filename
pipe=$2  #Total Pipe Value

#Filename to parse
if [ $filename -ne $1 ]
then
   echo "Filename required"
   exit 1
fi

#Check pipe/comma
if [ $pipe -ne $2 ]
then
   echo "Filename and number of expected pipes required"
   exit 1
fi
if [ -f $1 ]
then
while read -r line
do
((i+=1))
count=${line//[^|]}
echo Line#"$i:" "${#count}" pipe per line compare to "$2" expected
done <$filename
fi
if [ $count > $2 ]
then
echo Line# "$i" has "${#count}" pipe in total > uhs_sm_qa_csv.ksh.log
fi
exit 0
```

Output of `script`:

```
[root@uhspaastream01 scripts]# ksh uhs_sm_qa_csv.ksh test.txt 10
uhs_sm_qa_csv.ksh[6]: [: test.txt: no parent
Line#1: 1 pipe per line compare to 10 expected
Line#2: 1 pipe per line compare to 10 expected
Line#3: 1 pipe per line compare to 10 expected
Line#4: 1 pipe per line compare to 10 expected
Line#5: 1 pipe per line compare to 10 expected
```

Contents of `test.txt`:

```
cyberciti.biz|74.86.48.99
nixcraft.com|75.126.168.152
theos.in|75.126.168.153
cricketnow.in|75.126.168.154
vivekgite.com|75.126.168.155
```

Contents of the log file`uhs_sm_qa_csv.ksh.log`:

```
Line#5 has 1 pipe in total
```

Comment: If you're expecting two parameters to the script, you should probably test that `"$#" -eq 2` before assigning or using the parameters.

Comment: This looks like a very roundabout way to count / act on the number of separators per line: it would be far simpler IMHO to use `awk` or `perl` and use the number of fields minus 1 e.g. `awk -F'|' 'NF>n+1 {printf("Line# %d has %d pipe in total\n",NR,NF-1)}' n=2 filename`

Comment: @steeldriver Hmmm how would I implement that into my script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I find it odd that you're comparing a variable to something that you *just* set it to, the core issue is that you're using a numeric comparison operator `(-ne)` for what's expected to be a filename (of text). Instead, use:

```
if [ "$filename" != "$1" ]
```

... where I've also [quoted your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/117549).

Bonus points to [steeldriver's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/430675/ksh-script-no-parent-error/430678?noredirect=1#comment778142_430678), which prompted me to look a little further into this.

Based on my testing, I believe that ksh sees the `ne` *numeric* comparison operator and is performing a round of variable & arithmetic expansion on the two operands `$filename` and `$1`. As such, `$filename` turns into `test.txt`, which ksh recognizes as a possible [`compound variable`](https://blog.fpmurphy.com/2009/01/ksh93-compound-variables_05.html). Since `test` is unset, you receive the error `test.txt: no parent`.

Comment: Presumably the specific error `[: test.txt: no parent` is because (in the context of the `-ne` numeric test) `test.txt` is being interpreted as a [ksh93 compound variable](https://blog.fpmurphy.com/2009/01/ksh93-compound-variables_05.html) ?